UITableView - insertingRows at index 0 breaks the animation if scrolled slightly down
InsertingRows fails animation if the user is slightly scrolled.
https://gist.github.com/patryk-sredzinski/cbbf77a35e31dea707e5349194a10828

Tap on Insert to add a row - observe how it nicely scrolls
Move the collection view by one pixel
Tap again on Insert - observe how the animation ends and then the contentOffset jumps


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I have added it. It's on GiST Github
